# Laravel / Eloquent - Many to many pivot model with morphToMany relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have a manyToMany relationship set up and have modelled the pivot table also. Also, in the pivot model I have a morphToMany relationship set up.

Here is a diagrammatic representation of the setup.

[image: diagram]

The trouble I am having is that I can't pull in the joins attribute on the pivot model.

I have this code in my Dimension model;

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Datasource', 'dimension_datasource')->withPivot('joins');
```

But I get this error: Unknown column dimension_datasource.joins

I have tried setting up an accessor on the pivot model but it appears that it is being ignored as I get the same error.

Thanks,

Geoff

Comment: Please show your models, have you set a model for the pivot table? How have you set up the morph relation on the dimension_datasource table?

Comment: Yes, there is a Dimension_datasource_pivot model and a corresponding Dimension_datasource class which only has one method: newPivot which return an instance of Dimension_datasource_pivot. For the morph relation, I have a pivot table called 'joinables' which has Dimension_datasource_pivot as the joinable_type, where applicable.

Comment: Are your other models extending your new base pivot model?

Comment: Yes, DImension and Datasource each extend Dimension_datasource.

Comment: You should put your pivot tables names in alphabetical order. So it should be datasource_dimension

Comment: I have overridden the default table name in my Dimension_datasource_pivot class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working now. I'm distressed to admit I am not 100% sure why, but I'm fairly certain it was to do with the character encoding of backslashes in the fully qualified class names in the joinable_type column of the joinables table. So, if you are having the same issue, try looking there (there are indications elsewhere on the internet that Laravel should be escaping those backslashes and also vague suggestion of server settings being relevant).

Sorry I can't be more specific!!